# Blender 2.6: UV-Matching on Non-Image-Textures

Tags: textures, models, blender, uv-mapping

### Situation:

I want to model a piece of wood in Blender (2.63.0). In order to do this I use a set of `Noise` and `Clouds` textures on a brown material. But these textures are warped and shown in the wrong size.

### Question:

How can I do UV-matching on textures, which aren't of the `Image or Movie` type? Or is there another way to avoid texture warping? - Thanks for your answers or rather your ideas (and please tell my if anything isn't clear!).

Comment: You have to set the mapping to UV (the default is Generated) in the texture property panel if you want to use the UV coords.