# Blender 2.6: Move Mesh to X Coordinate of Another Mesh

Tags: models, movement, blender, 3d-meshes, coordinates

### An example:

There are two planes `A` and `B` with the following median points:

```
    ( X | Y | Z )

M_A ( 3 | 2 | 2 )
M_B ( 6 | 1 | 1 )
```

Now I want to move the plane `A` on the `X`-axis to the `X` coordinate of the plane `B` (the `Y` and the `Z` coordinate of plane `A` should stay the same). That's the desired result:

```
M_A ( 6 | 2 | 2 )
```

### My Question:

How can I **move** a mesh **to the `X` position of another** mesh (or to the `X` postition of the 3D cursor) without touching the `Y` and `Z` coordinates. - It's a bit like the Blender function called `Snap`, but what I want is **just about `X` coordinate**.

Thanks for your ideas (please comment if anything is unclear!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can constrain movement to an axis even when using the various snapping modes in Blender. 'g' to start a move, 'x' to constrain to the x axis, and hold down control to snap (change snapping modes in the popup menu next to the magnet on the toolbar).

Alternatively you can enter the coordinates directly in the object property panel.

Comment: Very thanks - I already knew about the functionality of `Ctrl`, but I wasn't aware that I can combine that with an axis constraint. Blender isn't always user friendly, but the `Grab` tool seems to be up really logical.

Comment: Oh, it's not really working as expected. - I press `x`, hold down the `Ctrl` key and move my cursor, but **it's simply not snapping**. My concrete use-case: I want to snap one edge to another edge of the same object. My settings from the `View` toolbar: "Snap": `TRUE` - "Snap Element": `Edge` - "Snap target": `Closest` - "Project to Self": `TRUE` - **Any idea concerning that?** - Thanks.

Comment: "Project to Self"? I don't know of that option when snapping to edges. Snapping edges together and constraining to the x axis works for me. See http://vimeo.com/27220020 for a few tips on how to use the snapping options.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the link to the video. - I don't know what the problem was, but I `grab`bed the problematic object manually, now I've tried it out on the mesh of another object and everything (except for [the UV matching problem](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46855/blender-2-6-uv-matching-on-non-image-textures)) **is fine** now.